# Ampersand in Cronjob

Tags: cron

I have found the following entry in a user crontab:

```
*/5  * * * *  ~/bin/php /path/to/phpscript &> /path/to/logfile
```

What is the meaning of the `&` (ampersand) here?
Has it still the meaning of running in background?
Does it make sense in a cronjob?

Comment: If you search for the string `&>` in the linked question, you will find the answer.

Comment: @Jenny D: I had posted the found answer already. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Stephen Kitt. Found the answer at [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators):

```
command &> out.txt
```

> Both standard error and standard output of command
>   will be saved in out.txt, overwriting its contents or creating it if
>   it doesn't exist.